# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/amazonaws/services/cognitosync/AmazonCognitoSync.class

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using AWS sdk for java for storing the app data in dynamodb and AWS sdk for android for using amazon services. But whenever I try to run the app it shows this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/amazonaws/services/cognitosync/AmazonCognitoSync.class

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:MaterialPreferenceLibrary:5'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.0'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.37'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.9'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.9'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.9'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.9'
```

I am stuck on it from hours. Please can someone help me with this

Thanks

Comment: `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` means we have no idea what your dependencies are. Try to `unzip` all of your jars to find the bad one.

Comment: @ScottM. I have tried that but still it is giving the same error